# How can I change onClick, elements on ionic v4 React and take effect on a specific place?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want on this code to type "Yes" or "No" on the row that I am clicking and not to all the rows. I ahve tried to do this with some id or class but nothing happened.Is it possible on this way or  I must change the hole code? I am using ionic framework v4 with React.

```
const arr = [
  {
    date: "1 Mar 2020",
    desc: "potatos",
    ap: "1"
  },
  {
    date: "2 Mar 2020",
    desc: "meat",
    ap: "2"
  }
];

const Meals: React.FC = () => {
  const [lablel, setLablel] = useState("");


  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle size="large" color="danger">
            Meals
          </IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent className="ion-padding">
        <IonList>
          {arr.map(elem => (
            <IonItemSliding key={elem.ap}>
              <IonItem>
                <IonAvatar>
                  <img
                    src={`https://example/avatar-${elem.desc.toLowerCase()}.png`}
                    alt=""
                  />
                </IonAvatar>
                <IonLabel className="ion-padding">
                  <h2>{elem.date}</h2>
                  <h2>
                    {elem.desc}
                    {Text}
                  </h2>
                  <h3 id={elem.ap}>{lablel}</h3>
                </IonLabel>
              </IonItem>
              <IonItemOptions side="start">
                <IonItemOption color="success" onClick={() => setLablel("Yes")}>
                  Yes
                </IonItemOption>
              </IonItemOptions>
              <IonItemOptions side="end">
                <IonItemOption color="danger" onClick={() => setLablel("No")}>
                  No
                </IonItemOption>
              </IonItemOptions>
            </IonItemSliding>
          ))}
        </IonList>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Meals;
```

Comment: Do you mean you want it to be with each item and be hidden untill you click on the item so it expand aditional class to show the yes/no buttons?

Comment: Yes something like that.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible

Comment: You can do it in normal css and html and add the js function as an item click method.